# Button Click not firing When focus is set to next cell in DataGridView on CellEndEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On Windows forms, I have a gridview with 3 columns and few buttons to handle data processing. The Grid is editable and I am using the below code to move focus to the next cell of the current row whenever a user presses the "Enter" key in editing mode.

```
private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1];
            }));
        }
    }
```

The code works fine and is moving the focus to next cell as required. However, the problem arises when I click any of the button while grid's cell is in focus. Since the focus is on a certain cell, clicking the button fires the **CellEndEdit** event before the **Click** event of the button and as a result of my code, the focus moves to next cell and the button click is not fired at all. I want to ensure that the code written to move to next cell in CellEndEdit function is not fired when i click a button.

1. Edit a cell in GridView, press Enter, focus moves to next cell - Correct
2. Edit a call in GridView, click on any button, focus moves to next cell, button click event not fired - **Problem**

I have searched a lot on SO and Internet regarding this issue but couldn't find a permanent solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand you, but what about, in the `CellBeginEdit`, store the previous value of the cell, and if in `CellEndEdit` is the same, don't move to the next cell?

Comment: The problem is not in moving to next cell, the problem is when I click any button on the form, the gridview fires CellEndEdit and the code moves to next cell. The button click is not fired at all. I have added more details to my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `ProcessCmdKey` of the `form`, check if `CurrentCell` is in edit mode and `Enter` was clicked:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter && this.dataGridView.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != this.dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            //this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            //{
                this.dataGridView.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[this.dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1];
            //}));
        }
        return true;
    }
    else return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can use instead the `KeyDown` event.

It could be like this:

```
private void dataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // the rest of your code

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyDown event is not fired when I press the Enter key while the cell is in edit mode. It is fired only when the cell is not in Edit mode.

Comment: Please see my other answer